# Menu bar fixed bottom screen after scrolling ~20px

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have managed to get the menu fixed when scrolling, it's ok. But unfortunately it hides some titles when use internal page links. So I would like to have the menu bar displayed at the bottom of the screen instead of the top (initial position when the page load) after scrolling approx. 20px...

Here is my code :

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function($) {

  var nav = $('.nav-container');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      nav.addClass("f-nav");
    } else {
      nav.removeClass("f-nav");
    }
  });

}); < /script>

    <script>
    $(function(){
    
    var nav = $('#nav'),
        pos = nav.offset();
        
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+nav.height() && nav.hasClass('default')){
                nav.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && nav.hasClass('fixed')){
                nav.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

```css
  .nav-container {
    background-color: white;
    repeat-x 0 0;
  }
  .f-nav {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav a {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .nav li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav.show {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">CSS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">PHP</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">SEO</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">jQuery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Wordpress</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Services</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's maybe not very "clean"... But anyone has an idea?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your navbar has 'no height'(because it's fixed) it will show the headers at the top of the page instead of below the element. Fix this by adding an anchor as below before your 'real' element (where you want to link to by clicking in the header).

```
<span id="**ITEM**" class="anchor"></span>
```

And add this to your CSS.

```
.anchor {
    display: block;
    height: 30px; /*same height as header*/
    margin-top: -30px; /*same height as header*/
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Hope this helped :)

You can see it working here on my [latest project](http://23-rulez.tk).(Click join in the header)

Comment: Many thanks, it works perfectly! And it will be better than my odd previous idea to put the menu bottom screen ;)    Cheers!